# Windows Update after moving "Users" to different disk on Windows 8 (Not using Registry)

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I would like to ask about something. I just got a new desktop PC with a 240 GB SSD, and a 1 TB HDD so I had to move the Users folder to the HDD. I used the way written here: http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-change-user-profile-location-in-windows-8-without-registry-hack/

I am wondering now, since this involves no registry hack, is it safe to run Windows Update? I tried yesterday but I ended up with 4 updates failing to install with all Microsoft Windows 8 apps (the ones in the new start) not detecting any Internet. I also could not add any features to the Windows as .Net Framework as anything Microsoft related failed to connect to the Internet.

I did a fresh install, followed the guide again but disabled the Windows Update, but I kind of need some updates to add few options to my systems, just basic Windows Updates not upgrading to Windows 8.1, so is it safe to do updates, is there something to do to make sure all updates will install fine, or should I just stay away of Windows Update?

In case it's ok to update, I want to make everything would work perfectly as I heard the guide I followed could sometimes do permission issues so which folders to check and make sure I got full permissions to so that none of the updates fail? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure its "ok" to update but it sounds like you have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to run windows update ? Yes but windows update might not even function fully.

The hack is not officially supported and some windows updates will definitely fail. Important updates such as windows 8 to 8.1 will fail for sure even if you do not use any registry hacks. Since 8.1 will be mandatory for recieving updates in the future, you will have to undo at some point. [Source](http://www.zdnet.com/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive-7000022142/)

The best alternative is to leave the Users folder as it is and move the libraries (Documents, Downloads, Music ...) to different drives. The officially supported way is to right click on the folders and specify the new location in the Location tab. [This page](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/windows-7-and-ssds-cutting-your-system-drive-down-to-size_p2/2941) gives a walkthrough of how to do it.